# Need help creating "successful authentication" page for spring security cas client

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, cas

I am using Spring MVC to write a client application that will authenticate against a Spring Security CAS server.

The problem that I am running into is, after a user authenticates successfully, the browser shows a 404 error. I am not sure how to set up a "success" page in my application. Or do I need to define a callback url somewhere in the CAS server properties? Here is my code so far:

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**applicationContext-security.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Enable security, let the casAuthenticationEntryPoint handle all intercepted 
    urls. The CAS_FILTER needs to be in the right position within the filter 
    chain. -->
<security:http entry-point-ref="casAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"></security:intercept-url>
    <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER"
        ref="casAuthenticationFilter"></security:custom-filter>
</security:http>

<!-- Required for the casProcessingFilter, so define it explicitly set and 
    specify an Id Even though the authenticationManager is created by default 
    when namespace based config is used. -->
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="casAuthenticationProvider"></security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- This section is used to configure CAS. The service is the actual redirect 
    that will be triggered after the CAS login sequence. -->
<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service"
        value="https://localhost:8443/cas/j_spring_cas_security_check"></property>
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false"></property>
</bean>

<!-- The CAS filter handles the redirect from the CAS server and starts 
    the ticket validation. -->
<bean id="casAuthenticationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"></property>
</bean>

<!-- The entryPoint intercepts all the CAS authentication requests. It redirects 
    to the CAS loginUrl for the CAS login page. -->
<bean id="casAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="https://localhost:8443/cas/login"></property>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Handles the CAS ticket processing. -->
<bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService"></property>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"></property>
    <property name="ticketValidator">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="https://localhost:8443/cas">
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="key" value="cas"></property>
</bean>

<!-- The users available for this application. -->
<security:user-service id="userService">
    <security:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER"></security:user>
</security:user-service>
```

I would appreciate any help!

The above code was used from the following tutorial: http://www.oudmaijer.com/2009/12/28/spring-3-spring-security-3-cas-3-3-4-integration/

---

Update: Here is the network flow (taken from Firebug):

1. User clicks on `https://localhost:8443/SpringMVC_CAS/secure/index.jsp`
2. Browser performs a "302 Moved Temporarily" from `/myapp/secure/index.jsp`
3. CAS prompts log-in `https://localhost:8443/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8443%2Fcas%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check`
4. `https://localhost:8443/cas/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=ST-17-RHf3OTJXAWePgzVGP2nc-cas`
5. Browser shows `https://localhost:8443/cas/login?ticket=ST-17-RHf3OTJXAWePgzVGP2nc-cas`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by adding an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` like this:

```
<bean id="casAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/casfailed.jsp"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If you set alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl property to true also, then the defaultTargetUrl will be used for the destination otherwise a redirect to the the original destination before the authentication process commenced will tke place.

See also:

- [SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html)
- [SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html)

Comment: Hi Ravi, thanks for your help. I resolved my 404 error (due to a mistake in one of my URL's). I also inserted your code, however I'm finding that on successful authentication, the browser is not redirecting to the page that I specified in defaultTargetUrl. Instead, CAS always flashes a "Login Successful" banner. Can you see anything else that I may be missing in my code? Is it possible that the CAS server settings override the casAuthenticationFilter? I tried setting alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl, and I also tried SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler. Both made no difference...

Comment: Here is the full text of the Login Successful banner: "You have successfully logged into the Central Authentication Service.
For security reasons, please logout and exit your web browser when you are done accessing services that require authentication!"

Comment: Try removing auto-config attribute or setting it to false on http element. You can also see this example which authenticates to a stateless service. https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-security/samples/cas/sample/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml?hb=true

Comment: Hi Ravi, I get the same result after both setting auto-config to false and removing it entirely. I also tried creating a separate project with the source code at the link you provided, and the same behavior happens again.

Comment: Can you check if the service property value is being sent as a parameter to the loginUrl?

Comment: Hi Ravi, please see the update at the bottom of my original post where I show the network flow. It looks like step #3 sends the service property value of https://localhost:8443/cas/j_spring_cas_security_check

Comment: the service property value should be https://localhost:8443/SpringMVC_CAS/j_spring_cas_security_check, the name of your webapp as it is a callback url.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it after days of scratching my head...